# Make a data frame with lists in a list that have similar structure without copy-paste

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list `B` with lists in it. I need to create a data frame with values in `B`. In my codes below, can I have the same result `data` without copy-paste `a1` and `a2` in the function? The problem is I have plenty of similar data like `a1`and `a2`, so if I type it individually it will go to `a20`,`a21`, etc.

```
B <- list(per1 = structure(list(t1 = c(1,2), t2 = c(3,4)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                         -2L), class = "data.frame"),
          per2 = structure(list(t1 = c(10,20), t2 = c(30,40)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -2L), class = "data.frame"))

fun <- function (df,k){
  data.frame (
    a1 = c (unlist(df[[1]][[k]], use.names = FALSE),
            unlist(df[[1]][[k]], use.names = FALSE)),
    a2 = c (unlist(df[[2]][[k]], use.names = FALSE),
            unlist(df[[2]][[k]], use.names = FALSE)))}
    
data <- fun (B,1)
```

Comment: Based on the example showed, `B` is a `list` of data.frames

Comment: Isn't `unlist(df[[1]][[k]]` repeated twice

Comment: Do you intend to just repeat everything in a1 and a2 etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data, showed, we could use `expand.grid`

```
f1 <- function(lstA, i) {
           expand.grid(setNames(lapply(lstA,
          `[[`, i), paste0('a', seq_along(lstA))))
 }
f1(B, 1)
#  a1 a2
#1  1 10
#2  2 10
#3  1 20
#4  2 20
```

---

Or to `rep`licate

```
f2 <- function(lstA, i) {data.frame(lapply(lstA, function(x) rep(x[[i]], length(lstA))))}
f2(B, 1)
  per1 per2
1    1   10
2    2   20
3    1   10
4    2   20
> f2(B, 2)
  per1 per2
1    3   30
2    4   40
3    3   30
4    4   40
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the functional programming approach of `purrr`

```
fun  <- function(input, k) {
   purrr::map_dfc(input, ~c (unlist(.x[[k]], use.names = FALSE), unlist(.x[[k]], use.names = FALSE)))
}

> fun(B, 1)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   per1  per2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    10
2     2    20
3     1    10
4     2    20
> fun(B, 2)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   per1  per2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3    30
2     4    40
3     3    30
4     4    40
```